# Передать программно объект при переходе через navigate

Tags: angular2, angular, angular-routing

Как передать данные при переходе на другой роут, чтобы не загружать их повторно?

Я просмотрел [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) и не нашел в нем ничего подходящего. В лучшем случае через его свойство [queryParams](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#queryParams) можно передать id для того чтобы загрузить объект повторно.

```
this.router.navigate(
    [`/tickets/buy`],
    {
        queryParams: {
            event: event.id
        }
    }
)
```

Еще была идея сделать сервис и получать данные через него, но это кажется слишком костыльным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С версии [7.2.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#720-2019-01-07) у класса `NavigationExtras` есть свойство [state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state). Пример:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

public navigateWithSomeState(): void {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/tickets/buy', {
    state: что угодно
  });
}
```

Состояние можно получить используя метод `getCurrentNavigation` роутера, который вернет объект типа `Navigation`. У `Navigation` есть свойство `extras`, а в свойстве `extras` как раз `state`:

```
class BuyTicketsComponent {
  constructor(router: Router) {
    console.log(router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state);
  }
}
```

Архитектура Angular заточена на SCA (service-component architecture), любое взаимодействие через сервисы нельзя назвать костылями.